Why does a high-reputation user refuse to correct an obvious falsehood even after it has been pointed out to him?
from the comments under the question
Do linguists consider that vowel length marks aren't necessary for AmE (and parhaps RP,too)?
the follwoing comments occur:

@SK No, OALD is based on BrE; where AmE pronunciation differs, it is listed separately, following the British one, and still using transcriptions that are based on BrE (with length marks, for example). And I did not insult or name-call, I merely pointed out that your statements are uninformed and incorrect, which they are. It’s clear from your disparaging comments that you do not like linguistics; that does not make it invalid. –
Janus Bahs Jacquet
CommentedJul 6 at 19:53


It is TOTALLY FALSE that OALD gives the AmE pronunciation only when it differs from BrE. Someone who can make such a blatantly false statement that can be verified in one second - cannot be given ANY credence on ANYTHING - Falsus in uno, falsus in omnibus @Janus Bahs Jacquet –
S K
CommentedJul 6 at 20:09
2


“If there is a difference between British and American pronunciations of a word, the British one is given first, with NAmE before the American pronunciation.” — OALD, p. R118. If you claim this is false, please provide just one example where they list a NAmE pronunciation that does not differ from the British one. –
Janus Bahs Jacquet
CommentedJul 6 at 20:47

All one has to do is to go to
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/
to see that to every word, both AmE and BrE pronunciations are given.
For truth-seekers - the sclerotic refusal of the group to correct errors and seek truth is very frustrating.  If SE has the goal of becoming a reference source for truth it has failed colossally because the high-rep participants impose censorship through up and downvotes.  Moderation ALWAYS = censorship.  The unmoderated usenet is a much better reference source than this forum. A lot of the contents of SE have a diseased feel to it - one feels one must use tongs to touch it.

Since you so obviously have problems with moderation, why are you still here? Moderation and earning privileges through reputation is a fundamental part of stack exchange, you can’t hope it to go away.

moderators can limit themselves to removing profanity, threats, and ad hominems.  But it happens UNIVERSALLY on SE that moderators get addicted to their petty power and act as tyrants.  There is also a Gadarene swine effect - contributions from me set off detonations in other participants' head.  I'll receive a gazillion downvotes if I post  "motherhood is good" @keelan

Westerners used to go into shock in the 1960s and 70s when they would go to third world countries and witness the shocking poverty.  I feel the same way when I witness the absolutely needless petty tyranny (both from moderatos and mob-downvoters) at SE. @keelan

After all - these are bits and bytes translated into words they fight over.  You could say they are fighting for truth - but they are quite demonstrably not doing that. I pointed out an easily verifiable falsehood - but and it means nothing to the moderators. @keelan

I go into shock half of the times I meet an American online these days to be honest.

I don't have access to the OALD, so I can't comment on the truth or falsehood of the claim.
But non-moderators can't edit comments after a certain period of time, which means that mistakes in comments (anything from typos to broken links to factual errors) stick around unless a moderator deletes them, which is generally a very low priority.

People are welcome to make (apparently) false statements in comments. This does not need any moderator intervention. You may only flag answers for being wrong or misleading. If you want to challenge something written in comments, you may leave another comment or you may ask a separate question about the topic, on the appropriate SE site, without targeting a specific user. You may flag comments if they break SE rules. It is helpful to think of comments as temporary artifacts of a Q&A site. So far, I notice that there are quite a lot of comments under the question. A few more such comments, and it becomes my duty to move them all to chat, thereby deleting them from under the question post.
So, about OALD, etc., I ain't reading all that.

I find the "ain't" disrespectful. @prash

@SK how dare you want me to censor myself!
